# Rake task not inserting to database when running on Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a `User.create` on my rake task but this code does not work:

```
require 'rake' 
require 'rails_helper'

feature "Should create a user when running task" do
   describe "should create user" do
        Rails.application.load_tasks
        Rake::Task['make_a:new_user'].invoke 
        expect(User.count).to be(1)
    end
end
```

I got

```
expected #<Fixnum:3> => 1
         got #<Fixnum:1> => 0
```

my rake file:

```
namespace :make_a do
  desc "Create a new user"
  task :new_user => :environment do
    User.create(email: "test@gmail.com", password: "test")
  end

end
```

Comment: Why you have added the rake task for create the user ???

Comment: @Bharatsoni No thats just an example, and am just curious why it wont load that way

Comment: Maybe the task doesn't actually work??? Please include the contents of the `make_a:new_user` rake task in your post; we need to see a *complete* (and ideally *verifiable*) example to properly understand the problem.

Comment: @TomLord added the rake file

Comment: `User.create(email: "test@gmail.com", password: "test")` does this create a user through console? I doubt it will rollback, there must be `password_confirmation` or some other validation, is it? or not?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon This literally is just a `password:string` and `email:string`. I have not yet inputted validations or even touched user.rb...

Comment: @wasabiMaster123 What happens if you use `create!`? What happens if you stick a `binding.pry` in the rake task, and investigate what exactly happens when you run this manually?

Comment: @TomLord Not sure how to create a binding.pry but ill research